# basic unique ModelForm field for Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, app-engine-patch

I do not care about concurrency issues.

It is relatively easy to build unique form field:

```
from django import forms

class UniqueUserEmailField(forms.CharField):
    def clean(self, value):
      self.check_uniqueness(super(UniqueUserEmailField, self).clean(value))

    def check_uniqueness(self, value):
        same_user = users.User.all().filter('email', value).get()
        if same_user:
          raise forms.ValidationError('%s already_registered' % value)
```

so one could add users on-the-fly. Editing existing user is tricky. This field would not allow to save user having other user email. At the same time it would not allow to save a user with the same email. What code do you use to put a field with uniqueness check into ModelForm?

Answer (score 1):

quick and dirty way would be:

1. make check_uniqueness classmethod
2. use custom field check in ModelForm, like this:

   ```
   class User(forms.ModelForm):    
       email = forms.EmailField()    
   def clean_email(self):
       data = self.cleaned_data['email']
       original = self.instance.email
       if original == data:
           return data
       UniqueUserEmailField.check_uniqueness(data)
       return data
   ```

better options?